# Visual Studio assembler window scrolls forever?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I put a break point in my C++, within Visual Studio 2012. I run the code, right click the line at which the break point as been encountered and then select "Go to Dissembly". A new window appears, showing what does look like the assembler for my program. However, when I begin to scroll up or down through the assembler the scrollbar starts getting larger and larger, as if my scrolling is creating additional assembler instructions (obviously this is what would really happen for the CPU- but surely the assembler window should only be showing assembler for my program- not my mouse scrolling????)

**Could someone confirm why the scrollbar keeps re-sizing, implying there is an unlimited amount of assembler?**

I just want to see:

> *begin of my program in assembler*
>
> ->> scroll ->>
>
> *end of my program in assembler*

in the assembler window (as opposed to outputting assembler files). The same thing happens with VS2010 too.

EDIT

The program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "test" << endl;
    int b = 0;
    cin >> b;
}
```

**Could it be because of the console window being open and cin >> waiting??**

Comment: I don't use that particular toolset, but for any non-trivial program the amount of assembly generated by the compiler will be huge. Clearly not infinite, but huge.

Comment: Five people decided this question was soooooooooo obvious..... they couldn't leave an answer....

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Hi- the program is very trivial (see edit).

Comment: It depends on how you are building, and what the toolset does when you ask for the disassebly, but the standard library is far from trivial and it might have been pulled into your program by means of the `cin`, `cout`. *Trivial* is *even simpler* than what you have there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The disassembly window is a memory viewer. 
It shows:

- The memory address
- The code bytes (once checked from the context menu)
- The disassembled code

The memory address range is not limited to the program's allocated memory, so you can scroll over the whole address space.

Microsoft expains the behavior of the scroll-bar [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bw53t5c.aspx):

> You will also notice that the vertical scrollbar operates in a
>   nonstandard manner. The address space of a modern computer is very
>   large, and it would be easy to get lost by grabbing the scrollbar
>   thumb and dragging it to a random location. For this reason, the thumb
>   is "springloaded" and always remains in the center of the scrollbar.
>   In native code applications, you can page up or down, but cannot
>   scroll about freely.